# deleted files lvm+ext4

Tags: kill, disaster

I did a stupidity. Using find command I deleted near 500GB of files.

is there a REAL way to recover it?

Comment: Try `extundelete`.

Comment: did not work. :/

Answer (score 4):

In general, no, there's no easy way to undelete files on most Unix filesystems.  For specific filetypes (such as photos), your prospects are a little better; see [this document](http://www.linux.com/archive/feed/56588), for example.

[This document](http://www.ehow.com/how_2064953_recover-deleted-files-linux.html) talks about using the `debugfs` command to recover deleted files, but I don't know if this is applicable to `ext4` (and as the article says, there's no guarantee of success).

Comment: Thank you!, I recovered a  lot with PHOTORECOVERY, mostly mp3 files!